# How to obtain the last factory reset time for an Android device?

Tags: android, adb, factory, reset

I am developing a security related app and would like to know when was the device previously factory reset? Is there any way to obtain this information?

I tried getting the last modified time for many files using the adb shell but some show 1970/1971/current date which is not consistent or accurate.

Comment: time since boot up is not the same as last factory reset time. Also my tested devices show file system times as 1970/1971/current date which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

adb shell "stat /cache | grep Modify"

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried getting modification time for some files, but the specific one you need to query is `/cache`.

The `/cache` folder is wiped when you factory reset your phone.

The command you would use is `adb shell "stat /cache | grep Modify"`. Which produces something like: `Modify: 2016-01-27 15:57:38.000000000`

Comment: $ adb shell "stat /cache | grep Modify"
**/system/bin/sh: stat: not found**   Also I check adb shell ls -l , it shows dates as shell@hammerhead:/ $ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x root     root              1971-06-09 18:31 acct
drwxrwx--- system   cache             **2016-03-23 01:42cache**
-rwxr-x--- root     root       272364 1969-12-31 16:00 charger
dr-x------ root     root              1971-06-09 18:31 config
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1971-06-09 18:31 d -> /sys/kernel/debug
drwxrwx--x system   system            2016-03-23 09:45 data

Comment: cache shows today's date which is not true. this test was done on nexus 5.